# Deploying Rails Engine on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Does anyone know how to deploy a rails engine on heroku? The engine that I am developing is self contained so I am trying to avoid making another wrapper rails application to deploy my engine.

**FIXED**

I had to add config.ru and Procfile in my engine root directory to so that heroku knows that its a rails application.

Thanks,
Ajay

Comment: can you share the code that you used in your config.ru? I've been trying to figure out how to do this too.

Comment: I agree, please share your config.ru.

Comment: I would also be glad if you shared your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess is more dependant on how you've built your engine.  If you can run it standalone locally, it'll run just fine like that on Heroku - there's nothing about Heroku which would make running your code any harder other than the [normal constraints](http://devcenter.heroku.com/constraints)

Comment: I run the engine from dummy application created by default. How would heroku know that it has to start the dummy application?

Comment: ka8725, I was not trying to deploy a rails app but I was trying to deploy a rails engine. There are no rake db:seed, db:migrate etc in my case

Answer (score 0):

As the edit of the question states, `config.ru` and `Procfile` are needed. I just copied `config.ru` from a Rails app and changed the path:

```
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

require ::File.expand_path('../test/dummy/config/environment', __FILE__)
run Rails.application
```

As for `Procfile`, the following will work:

```
web: bundle exec rackup -p $PORT
```

You may want to add a gem for web server, as it will default to WEBrick which is not suitable for production.

In order to get proper logs on Heroku, add the following to the `Gemfile`

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Assets compilation won’t work unless you define the `assets:precompile` task (according to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#rails-4-x-applications-compile-phase).

I just added the following to engine’s `Rakefile`:

```
namespace :assets do
  desc 'Precompile assets within dummy app'
  task :precompile do
    Dir.chdir('test/dummy') do
      system('bundle exec rake assets:precompile')
    end
  end
end
```

I also disabled JS compression (or you can add `uglifier` gem to the Gemfile).